# ImportXML get content cannot be parsed with Google Sheets

Tags: xml, twitter, import, google-sheets, screen-scraping

I can't seem to get the Twitter bio and get "content cannot be parsed". I can get the likes associated with the Twitter account.

What is wrong with the line I'm using?

```
=importXML("http://twitter.com/"&substitute(A4,"@","",2),"//p[@class=’ProfileHeaderCard-bio u-dir’]")
```

A4=jaredhuet in google sheets.

Comment: Few people are clairvoyant enough to know what's in cell A4 of your spreadsheet. In any case, most webpages cannot be parsed with importXML for the simple reason that they are not XML.

Comment: see below for the reason and the workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual reason it doesnt work with twitter is because it is not properly formatted in the source, it is `malformed xml` so it isnt parseable with just importxml, however the below formula gets you the same thing, and it processes quicker and easier because there is less data to load and sift through.

Replace the twitter.com part with:

```
"https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name="&A41
```

the full formula is:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name="&A4,"//*[@class='note']")
```

[image]

Note the the `@` sign doesnt affect whether the page loads or not, but here is the working formula to grab that piece:

[image]